# Solving nullabe function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function and flutter have a problem becouse go to be null

```
 Widget getPicker() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return iOSPicker();
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return androidDropdown();
    }
  }
```

I try to make it async

```
Future<Widget> getPicker() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return iOSPicker();
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return androidDropdown();
    }
  }
```

But problem still here. How i can solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tweaking your if statement this way :

```dart
 Widget getPicker() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return iOSPicker();
    }
    return androidDropdown();
  }
```

You can also use `ternary` operator:

```dart
 Widget getPicker() {
    return Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropdown();
  }
```